# Android tour guide app need help and suggestions

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have planned to build an Android app for my final year project, that will help people in find places to visit, top places in an area when they search for one, etc
And when they will click on that place it will give a small summary about it and also the restaurant, movie theater, cafes, etc in that place.
So what all things I'll be requiring for this i have some knowledge about core java and gui part of it, 
But never tried android so a bit confused where to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking for tutorial recommendations are off-topic and too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it really is an question that's off topic and isn't really a question, I will try to simply aim you in the right direction.

First of all you need to search for an API service that will give you the information you want (like places near you, try foursquare or something similar). As I never worked with that API I don't exactly know what information's it needs and what information's you will receive from it, but firstly try reading their documentation.

Once you get the data you will have to display it somewhere/somehow but as I saw you have some GUI knowledge, however this wont be the hard part. This is your preference and imagination by how you do it and there are many online tutorials on how to use the items (ex. lists, alert dialog...)

Hope this helps and puts you to the right start. In the near future try asking more narrow and pointed questions and read the documentation on how to post one.

Happy coding and learning.

Comment: Apologies for the question and thank you sir for your suggestions